# Pedigree probability question

Tags: genetics, pedigree

The following pedigree shows the inheritance pattern of a trait. From the following, select the possible mode of inheritance and the probability that the daughter in generation III will show the trait.
a) X-linked recessive, probability is 1/2
b) X-linked recessive, probability is 1/4
c) Autosomal recessive, probability is 1/2
d) Autosomal recessive, probability is 1/3

[image]

This question is from an examination. The answer key says c) is the answer. I get how c) could be the answer, but I also think a) is a possibility. Please tell me if a) is possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it cannot be X-linked recessive, because in this case, the right-most son would have a trait.

[image: Inheritance]